How to increase shelf-life of homemade bean (legumes) paste
Most vegan dips and creams are legume-based. Legumes, however, turn bad pretty quickly.
I know that sodium bicarb helps to slow down the process, but it also makes the taste worse. What other options are there to have the cream/paste last longer?
Add-on: Naturally, I only use clean utensils and cool it down asap.
I mean store-bought hummus for e.g. is good for a week at least after opening. What ingredients or treatments that I could do at home, would achieve something similar?

Are you actually asking about shelf life (i.e. unrefrigerated storage), or do you just want the stuff to last longer in the refrigerator?

The second one. I want it last longer. Thank you

It's possible that the store bought stuff has been pasteurized in some way.  I don't know if getting a sous vide setup and doing a low temperature multi-hour cook might achieve what you're asking

Pasteurizing is an idea. Couldn't I do it in a pressure cooker?

An ice cube tray, and your freezer. After freezing in the ice cube tray, remove and bag the cubes and put back in freezer (vacuum-bagging optional.)
I strongly suggest having a dedicated tray or trays for this purpose, as even dishwasher safe ones typically retain some staining that you might not want your regular ice cubes exposed to.
If you know you'll want a large amount at once, you can simply freeze in a larger bag or container; the cubes are handier to portion out as much or as little as you want at a given point.

I prefer small lidded plastic storage containers - enough for 1 or 2 days' worth depending on your schedule - as they transport better to work for lunch and store better in the work fridge (using my case as an illustrative example). But the principle is the same. And yes, don't use the same tray for ice, especially if it's a silicone one and you like your hummus garlicky. The flavour is hard to get out.

Sanitize your utensils and storage containers, and cool the paste down quickly to fridge temps after you cook it. Use clean utensils every time you want to take some of the dip and lid it soon after.

It may also be better to use multiple smaller containers... they can be cooled down faster, and you don't has as long between dipping a utensil into it until it's used up.

That's what I am doing already. It still turns bad much too fast. Store-bought hummus for e.g. is good for at least a week after opening. What ingredients or treatments that I could do at home, would achieve something similar?

@Sebastian I don't have any at the moment, and it might be different to yours anyway, but does yours state a time after opening within which it should be used? I think I'm used to it saying 2 days, and me pushing that to 3 or 4.  That suggests either packing in a way that prevents contamination, packing under a protective atmosphere, or both.  Neither of these is readily doable at home
